# How to pass variables between class based Views in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've created url-shorter service using Django. For creating short link i use CreateView:

```
class LinkCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateLink
    template_name = "index.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users_links')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            form.instance.creator = self.request.user

        self.link_short = generate_short_link()
        
        self.request.session["new_link"] = self.link_short

        form.instance.link_short = self.link_short
        return super().form_valid(form)

    # Showing last 5 shorted links on the page
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = URL.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
        return context
```

After creating new link user is redirected to page "users_links" where he should see new shotred link. For this reason in template i use something like that:

```
{% if request.session.new_link %}
    <div>
        Your new link: request.session.new_link
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The problem is user see that 'div' all the time till the end of session. I think this is wrong decision to using session variables in this case, but i don't know how to pass variable between views in another way.

I'm newbie in Django, can you please give me advice how to do it in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for url in object_list %}
<div>
Your new link: {{url}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Maybe do the introduction of Django first before jumping in CBV, showing variable should be pretty easy and CBV are a bit abstracts so it is better to understand how they work.

object_list is not a good variable name either, you should call it "links" because you return a list of links.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've fixed it by adding checking for existed variable in session (and deleting if so) at the end of "the get_context_data" function in View that following after creating shortened URL.